# Error trying load Session Driver Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I´m trying to load the session driver on CI 3.

O configure the config/autoload.php with this:

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
```

So, I get this error:

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: require(/home/admin/web/mysite/public_html/system/libraries/Driver.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 699
```

Comment: installation you have is either broken or incomplete. AFAIK `Driver.php` is there in system libraries. [HERE](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/system/libraries)

Comment: I reupload everything in system/library and now it´s working! Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Session should be loaded in libraries, not drivers.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```